# How to set user name in container of kubernetes pod?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a following pod yaml to run a pod with security context where `runAsUser` and `runAsGroup` are set.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test
    image: ubuntu:18.04
    command: ["sleep", "10d"]
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 1002
      runAsGroup: 2002
```

When I exec into the container, it says:

```
$ k exec -it test -- bash
groups: cannot find name for group ID 2002
I have no name!@test:/$
```

whoami command is also not working:

```
I have no name!@test:/$ whoami
whoami: cannot find name for user ID 1002
```

Here I need to set username for given uid(uid is not fixed so can't create image with a specific username).

Does kubernetes provide any option to set username?

Answer (score 2):

No.  The username (if any) is determined by looking up the numeric user ID in the container's `/etc/passwd` file (if any), and Kubernetes doesn't try to modify that file.

There aren't really any consequences to the user ID not existing in `/etc/passwd`, beyond getting this cosmetic error message in the unusual case of a debugging shell.  Filesystem permissions are set and enforced only based on the numeric user and group IDs.  So, for example, if you mount a PersistentVolumeClaim with an additional `fsGroup:` setting, that's based only on a *numeric* group ID, and again, it's irrelevant whether or not that actually exists in the container's `/etc/groups` file.